# Can an app trigger data transfer functionality when plugged into a pc?

Tags: android, data-transfer

I am interested in making my app recognize that it has been plugged into a pc. Ideally it would do this on it's own as some sort of background check, but I would settle for having the check done actively by a button somewhere within the app. Specifically, I would like the app to transfer a series of text files which have been created by my app (stored on the SD card) to somewhere on the pc's storage. If possible, would the app be able to browse the pc's file tree to allow the user to define the location of the transferred files?

Thanks!

Comment: You'd need to go about it the other way.  The app would need to be on the PC side (or at least part of it).  Computers don't just automatically let attachments write to the filesystem.  Now an app on the PC could detect the connection via USB, then use USB mass storage to download the files wherever.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you connect the device to the PC using the mass storage option, the phone's sdcard is not available to the device but it is mounted on the computer. So in my opinion you're idea could not be implemented.